# Is there something like a linter/formatter/correctness checker for Doxygen blocks for C++?

Tags: formatting, whitespace, doxygen

Here are some things that would reduce a lot of repetition day-to-day:

- Automatically "flag" or alert me doxygen blocks where the number of `param` sections does not match the number of arguments in the function declaration below it
- Ideally, tell me if the names of the parameters don't match as well
- Flag/alert me to doxygen blocks whose params are missing `[in]`, `[out]` or `[in,out]`. Ideally, auto-fill anything marked `const` as `[in]`
- Something to convert between `\` and `@` for sections all at once rather than doing it ~4 times with find and replace.
- Something to format the blocks in a pretty way. As an example, here is a simple doxygen block that I consider "unformatted":

```
  /**
   * \brief Given a position in the grid, this updates the per-code bounds.
   * \param[in] code - The code we are adjusting the bounds of
   * \param[in] position1 - The new lower position
   * \param[in] position2 - The position of the lower cell within the high-level cell, 
   * this has a long description that may wrap over a couple lines.
   * \return How many positions we had to move
   */
  int updateExtents(
      const ObjCode code,
      const Geo::Point<uint8_t>& upperPos,
      const Geo::Point<uint8_t>& lowerPos);
```

And here's what it looks like with a little touch-up:

```
  /**
   * \brief Given a position in the grid, this updates the per-code bounds.

   * \param[in] code       - The code we are adjusting the bounds of
   * \param[in] position1  - The new lower position
   * \param[in] position2  - The position of the lower cell within the high-level cell, 
   *                         this has a long description that may wrap over a 
                             couple lines.

   * \return How many positions we had to move
   */
  int updateExtents(
      const ObjCode code,
      const Geo::Point<uint8_t>& upperPos,
      const Geo::Point<uint8_t>& lowerPos);
```

This is highly subjective, but the descriptions of each parameters are now aligned to the nearest tab, and wrap at that point rather than back at the beginning. I find it makes it a lot more readable.

Comment: Formating is an "IDE/ editor" task: what is your editor/IDE. The most famous ones have support for snippet. in Visual Studio code for instance you could create snippets that more or less automate thoses tasks (quering the user, formating, repeating stuff...). Most of the warning about missing documentation are already raised by doxygen itself when parsing the code. You can even find already made plugins: eg this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen

Comment: I am currently working with QTCreator.